# redirect from action to the same page

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

For example on every page I allow user to authorize himself. But in action `LoginAction` I move him to `main.jsp` every time because `req.getRequestURI` returns url with action in it
`localhost:8080/reservation/LoginAction.do`.

Here is `LoginAction`

```
     HttpSession session = req.getSession();

    log.debug("attempt to checkuser");

    String login = req.getParameter("login");
    String password = req.getParameter("password");

    if (loginService.checkExists(login, password)) {
        session.setAttribute("enterAttr", true);
        session.setAttribute("loginame", login);
        return "main";
    }

    session.setAttribute("enterAttr", false);
    return "redirect:/reservation/main.jsp";
```

How to get page that cause action?

Form on page looks like this

```
<form action="LoginAction.do" method="POST">
            <div id="table"
                class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-widget-content">
                <table align="center" style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center"><span
                            style="color: white; font-size: 20px;"><fmt:message
                                    key="lg" /></span></td>
                        <td align="right"><input type="text" id="login" name="login" />
                        <td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center"><span
                            style="color: white; font-size: 20px;"><fmt:message
                                    key="paswd" /></span></td>
                        <td align="right"><input type="password" id="password"
                            name="password" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" colspan="2"><input type="submit"
                            id="approve" style="font-size: 10px;"
                            value="<fmt:message key='enter'/>" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I am using this, I have hidden filed in form, that contains actual URL (or page). After login user, I use that value to redirect to last page.

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect_page" value="some_info" />
```

Comment: and you read it in action like this `string value = req.getGetparameter(redirect_page)`?

Comment: Yes...thats the way I am using this